LLAMA2 system prompt for RAG
Working on LLAMA2 to make a Retrieval Augmented Generation system. I have been using the meta provided default prompt which was mentioned in their paper. But this prompt doesn't seem to work well on RAG. It is making the bot too restrictive, and the bot refuses to answer some questions (like "Who is the CEO of the XYZ company?") giving some security related excuse, even if the information is present in the provided context. I am following the formatting recommended by meta. But for open-book question-answering, the only modification I made is to add context. For example, the original prompt format is the following:
<s>[INST] <<SYS>>
{{ system_prompt }}
<</SYS>>

{{ user_message }} [/INST]

After adding the context information, it changes as the following:
<s>[INST] <<SYS>>
{{ system_prompt }}

{{ context }}
<</SYS>>

{{ user_message }} [/INST]

But overall, the LLAMA2 seems to be too stubborn and often ignores the instructions provided in the system prompt. Sometimes it becomes too restrictive and sometimes it becomes too open and answers anything from its previous knowledge.
The general goal I want to achieve contains the followings:

Grounding the LLM, making it not to answer when the information is present in the context, even if it knows it. Preferably giving a preset custom fallback response.
Giving answer when the information is available in the context.
Not exposing the fact that it has been instructed to follow some prompt, rather behave like these restrictions are simply its own behavior without saying like: "... but I am not allowed to ..." etc.
Immune to prompt injection. As much as possible.
Preferably, trying to answer within a predefined certain number of tokens.

Can you suggest me a system prompt which can promisingly achieve this? I have tried various prompts available on the Internet. But most of them don't work well with LLAMA2.

Why not use llama3?

@FranckDernoncourt yea, that's true. But the only reason to choose LLAMA2 is its less parameter count. The minimum version of it comes with 7B parameters, whereas the minimum version for LLAMA3 is 8B. There are also some other models I tried like Mistral 7B which is just better than LLAMA2. But still, I want to know what else I am missing to get the desired output in LLAMA2. These insights can still help in prompting better models.
